# What is the Rocky Linux/Centos 8 equivalent to system-config-printer?

Tags: linux, printer, centos-8

The system-config-printer command is not found and is not available through yum. My program needs to run the system graphical printer setup command. Is "gsd-printer" equivalent? (I am remote and unable to make x11vnc work even with Wayland off so I cannot test it).

UPDATE

I asked my co-worker to run printer setup. I think it was started from gnome-control-center (which has a printers panel argument). But we are using sddm for the display manager.

Comment: RHEL 8 doc : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deploying_different_types_of_servers/configuring-printing_deploying-different-types-of-servers

Comment: Thanks. We might have to use the CUPS web UI but this is a kiosk application.

Comment: Testing with Rocky 8 : CUPS → Enter URL `localhost:631` in a browser , 'Add Printer' as root, set as default ..... and you can print. ( I had no issues, with a random hp printer : Seems `hplip-common` was installed with the OS install 3 months ago.) **Note** : No Internet connection is required.

Comment: We may go with this.  It maintains kiosk mode but there is no way to exit so timeout will close it.  
timeout 180 firefox -kiosk localhost:631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can now run gnome-control-center panels without switching to Gnome.

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 gnome-control-center $PANEL

I have tested PANEL="printers" or "datetime". One glitch is that you can switch from datetime to printers.

I used the "...localauthority..." solution. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399635/remove-unlock-option-from-gnome-control-center

The policy files were in "/usr/share/polkit-1/actions" for the Action= line.

I set permissions, owner and group in "/usr/share/applications/" to control panel availability. https://askubuntu.com/questions/442520/is-it-possible-to-remove-items-from-system-settings